# How can I format this array of objects to another object format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, format

First of all I am sorry If I couldn't explained my problem because it is really hard for me to explain it but If you need more information I will try answer all. So I am trying to format this array of objects

```
[
    {
        "time": "18th",
        "open": 100,
        "closed": 60,
        "waiting": 12
    },
    {
        "time": "20th",
        "open": 120,
        "closed": 80,
        "waiting": 75
    },
    {
        "time": "22nd",
        "open": 170,
        "closed": 0,
        "waiting": 34
    },
]
```

To this in javascript. I don't know what to do, I am not even sure if I can really format it, I need to create a dynamic chart and I realised that I can't do it with the first format due to library restrictions.

```
{
    "time": ["18th", "20th", "22nd"],
    "graphData": [
        {
            "label": "open",
            "data": [100, 120, 170],
        },
        {
            "label": "closed",
            "data": [60, 80, 0],
        },
        {
            "label": "waiting",
            "data": [12, 75, 34],
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Create all the inner arrays. Then loop over the original array, pushing each property onto the appropriate array. Finally, combine them all into the result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative by using the function `Array.prototype.forEach` which loops once.

```js
const result = {time: [], graphData: {}},
      source = [{"time": "18th","open": 100,"closed": 60,"waiting": 12},{"time": "20th","open": 120,"closed": 80,"waiting": 75},{"time": "22nd","open": 170,"closed": 0,"waiting": 34},];
      
source.forEach(({time, open, closed, waiting}) => {
  result.time.push(time);

  (result.graphData["open"] || (result.graphData["open"] = {label: "open", data: []})).data.push(open);
  (result.graphData["closed"] || (result.graphData["closed"] = {label: "closed", data: []})).data.push(closed);
  (result.graphData["waiting"] || (result.graphData["waiting"] = {label: "waiting", data: []})).data.push(waiting);
});

result.graphData = Object.values(result.graphData);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const source = [
    {
        "time": "18th",
        "open": 100,
        "closed": 60,
        "waiting": 12
    },
    {
        "time": "20th",
        "open": 120,
        "closed": 80,
        "waiting": 75
    },
    {
        "time": "22nd",
        "open": 170,
        "closed": 0,
        "waiting": 34
    },
];

const mapped = {
  time: source.map(item => item.time),
  graphData: ['open', 'closed', 'waiting']
    .map(label => ({label, data: source.map(item => item[label])}))
};

console.log(mapped);
```